# How to run an imported maven based mule project in Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

My mule maven based project created in eclipse is checked into svn. I want to run it in Anypoint Studio. So I imported it as Maven based project from SVN. But Studio doesn't recognize it as Mule project. Any pointers?

Answer (score 1):

If your project is a Maven project then it should be having a pom.xml file. From anypoint studio do an import of Maven project from pom.xml and point to the location where your project resides. it should automatically find the pom.xml inside and import it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your scenario correctly here is the solution.

Download the project from svn to a local folder.

From the command prompt run the command **mvn studio:studio** on this project

Then import the project into the studio from the tab
Import --> General --> Existing Project Into Workspace

Now you can directly run the project as a Mule project.

Hope this helps.