# Cannot run Mule project from within Anypoint Studio; ResourceException

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio

**Problem:**

When I want to run a project from within Anypoint Studio I am encountering a problem. This project was originally setup in Eclipse Juno with the Mule IDE plugin.

From within Eclipse Juno I was able to run the mule-config.xml on a local installation Mule Server.

Now I have upgraded to the latest Anypoint Studio (5.3.1; I have both the standalone and the plug-in with Eclipse Mars). I was successful in importing the project in the Anypoint environment and building it with Maven.

In both (standalone and plug-in) I am not able to run the project. When I try running through ‘Run Configurations’ I get an error where it complains that a resource is not available. But I don’t understand this error, because the resource `/XmlProxyValidationFilter` it is complaining about is a custom filter within my project in `src/main/java` which is on my build path (all included, none excluded).

**Definition of the custom filter:**

```
<custom-filter name="xmlValidatieRequestFilter" class="nl.xxx.icc.mule.XmlProxyValidationFilter">
    <spring:property name="xsdRepositoryBean" ref="iccXsdRepositoryBean" />
</custom-filter>
```

**Calling the custom filter from a flow:**

```
<flow name="xmlproxy.validator">
    <!-- some other stuff -->
    <filter ref="xmlValidatieRequestFilter" />
</flow>
```

*This flow validates an XML-message that is passing through against its corresponding XSD which is in the xsdRepositoryBean.*

**What I have tried:**

1. In Run-configurations I have chosen my project in `Mule domains/projects` (expecting it to be added to the classpath) and Mule Server 3.4.0 CE as `Target Server Runtime` (same runtime as with successful Maven-build).
2. In Run-configurations tried to add the missing resource to User Entries on the Classpath tab.
3. I have found a suggestion to try in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31683092/how-to-run-an-imported-maven-based-mule-project-in-anypoint-studio?rq=1) question, but I am not sure how to do this since I use Maven integrated in Eclipse. Therefor I have tried converting my project to a `Maven project` (I think this is a function specific to the Anypoint plug-in) but this does not solve the problem.
4. Tried to find similar problems for possible solutions, but only the above came close.

**Question:**

Any ideas why I am getting an error about a missing resource when I try to run the flow, while this resource is in my project-folder and I can build the project without problems with Maven?

**Error-log:**

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_31
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product

org.mule.tooling.core
Error
Wed Oct 21 08:00:33 CEST 2015
Unable to package application ZIP file

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ExportPackageManager.export(ExportPackageManager.java:87)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.DefaultDeploymentStrategy.packageZipFile(DefaultDeploymentStrategy.java:55)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.DefaultDeploymentStrategy.deployToEmbeddedInstance(DefaultDeploymentStrategy.java:26)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.deployProjects(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:486)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.performLegacyDeployment(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:344)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.launch(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/XmlProxyValidationFilter' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.hasNature(Project.java:521)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyArtifacts(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:621)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyReferencedProjectsArtifactsRecursively(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:615)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyReferencedProjectsArtifacts(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:608)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.MuleApplicationExportDelegate.export(MuleApplicationExportDelegate.java:41)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ExportPackageManager.doExport(ExportPackageManager.java:93)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ExportPackageManager.export(ExportPackageManager.java:85)
    ... 10 more
Root exception:
org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.ResourceException: Resource '/XmlProxyValidationFilter' does not exist.
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkExists(Resource.java:334)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Resource.checkAccessible(Resource.java:208)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.checkAccessible(Project.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Project.hasNature(Project.java:521)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyArtifacts(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:621)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyReferencedProjectsArtifactsRecursively(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:615)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.deployer.MuleApplicationDeployment.copyReferencedProjectsArtifacts(MuleApplicationDeployment.java:608)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.MuleApplicationExportDelegate.export(MuleApplicationExportDelegate.java:41)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ExportPackageManager.doExport(ExportPackageManager.java:93)
    at org.mule.tooling.core.packageManager.ExportPackageManager.export(ExportPackageManager.java:85)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.DefaultDeploymentStrategy.packageZipFile(DefaultDeploymentStrategy.java:55)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.DefaultDeploymentStrategy.deployToEmbeddedInstance(DefaultDeploymentStrategy.java:26)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.deployProjects(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:486)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.performLegacyDeployment(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:344)
    at org.mule.tooling.runtime.launch.MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.launch(MuleRuntimeLaunchDelegate.java:238)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:885)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:739)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1039)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1256)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: What is this `/XmlProxyValidationFilter` resource that Mule can't find? It looks like a weird name: where does it come from?

Comment: @David Dossot, thanks for your reply. `/XmlProxyValidationFilter` is a custom filter that we use in our project.

Comment: I have never seen such a name been used in a Mule app. Can you share bits of your config where this is defined and referred to? Of course, without disclosing any private info.

Comment: @David, the name is just the label we gave it. I have added some more info about how we use the custom filter.

Comment: Is the `nl.xxx.icc.mule.XmlProxyValidationFilter` class in a directory that is on the project build path?

Comment: @David, yes it is in /src/main/java which is on my build-path (everything is included and nothing is excluded)

Comment: Sorry no idea what's going here. Unfortunately `org.mule.tooling.core.deployer` is not open source so I can't try to figure out what's happening. I suggest you report this as a bug to MuleSoft.

Comment: @DavidDossot, thanks for your time. I will probably do that.

Answer (score 0):

@Jeroen Akershoek  ... I have faced same issue. So please put your resource in src/main/resource directory and use class path loader in your filter jar.